# Is this smart contract possible to make?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design

I want to make a smart contract that will give me an upper edge when it comes to buying into icos. Basically once a condition is met, for example the block reaches a certain number or a specific date requirement is met all the eth in a wallet will be sent to the pre coded wallet address.

I'ts a fairly simple idea but was wondering if something like this is what smart contracts were made to do. A simple yes or no and maybe a pointer is more than enough, I'll figure out how to make it on my own. I know Python 3 and Java, I know smart contracts are coded in JS which is pretty close to Java so I shouldn't have a problem figuring this out.

Comment: If you like python you should look into serpent for writing smart contracts https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Serpent

Answer (score 2):

@Krio, you can make it with an external oracle, for example, using Ethereum Alarm Clock http://www.ethereum-alarm-clock.com/

Ethereum Alarm Clock:

- Schedule Contract Function Calls
- An ethereum contract that facilitates scheduling function calls for a specified block in the future.
- Function calls can be scheduled to be executed against any contract
- Scheduling can be done by contracts or ethereum account holders.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/37663/is-it-possible-to-schedule-function-calls-to-an-ethereum-smart-contract

It is not possible to schedule a transaction in a contract.

Comment: This is not true. You can use Ethereum Alarm Clock for scheduling and many other solutions.